# When $touched is set in custom form controls?

Tags: angularjs

When $touched property is set in custom form controls? Should I set it manually or it is set by some ngModelControllers methods?

```
   <my-custom-form-control ng-model="value" name="myName"></my-custom-form-control>
   <div ng-messages="form.$errors" ng-if="form.myName.$touched">
     <div ng-message="myCustomError">My custom error</div>
   </div>
```

Let's say `my-custom-form-control` doesn't contain any input element

Answer (score 1):

It should be done manulally. By using $setTouched method on ngModelController or fire blur event on directive element.

Answer (score 0):

It is handled automatically by the angular form.

if you display the form `{{myName}}` in your DOM

you should see **$invalid**, **$touched** and other variables which will change value depending if you have invalid data / has blurred an input element

Comment: but my custom form control don't have an input :) it only contains buttons and labels